# ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND with SHLoadDIBitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, windows-ce

I want to load bitmap in WinAPI program
Application is developed for WindowsCE 2013. (Visual Studio 2013)
I specify full path, which in mine is correct, but GetLastError() function return error 3 (ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)

This is code's snippet below:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    //HDC hdc;
    HDC hdcOkno;
    hdcOkno = GetDC(hWnd);
    HBITMAP hbmObraz;
    hbmObraz = (HBITMAP)SHLoadDIBitmap(L"C:\\Users\\tykab\\OneDrive\\Dokumenty\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WinAPI\\WinAPI\\blue.bmp");
    DWORD error;
    error = GetLastError();
    BITMAP bmInfo;
    GetObject(hbmObraz, sizeof(bmInfo), &bmInfo);
    BitBlt(hdcOkno, 50, 50, bmInfo.bmWidth, bmInfo.bmHeight, hdcOkno, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: typo `Projects\WinAPI` should be `Projects\\WinAPI`

Comment: [SHLoadDIBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa453720(v=msdn.10)) doesn't claim to set the last error code. It's also unclear from the question, what the observed behavior is. Does `hbmObraz` have a non-NULL value after the call?

Comment: Ok, so my stupid mistake, but when I correct this with follow your advice I get error 3 (ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: @IInspectable 
hbmObraz return a NULL value

Comment: Are you sure that `Dokumenty` is really named like that and it is not just localized name for `Documents` used in Explorer?

Comment: @user7860670 Yes, I am sure. I tried both. This path is copied from explorer.

Comment: Some UI widgets in Windows' File Explorer contain *invisible* Unicode characters. Try opening your source file in a hex editor and see whether any characters slipped in. Alternatively, rewrite the path from your keyboard.

Comment: @BartłomiejTyka don't hard code the entire path. Query the OS in code for system-defined paths, like Documents and OneDrive, etc, and then append user-defined folders/files as needed. Also, as IInspectable said, `SHLoadDIBitmap()` is not documented as using `GetLastError()` for error reporting, so you can't rely on its value in this situation. All you can rely on is whether `hbmObraz` is NULL or not. And when it is not NULL, make sure you call `DeleteObject()` when you are done using it.

Comment: Put `blue.bmp` in `C:\blue.bmp` and try to load it with path `L"C:\\blue.bmp"`. If it succeedes copy it to `C:\tykab\blue.bmp` and try to load with `L"C:\\tykab\\blue.bmp"`. Go deeper and deeper until it fails.